# Point Estimate for B_1

Tags: regression, inference

[image]

How do I find the point estimate for B1? Pretty lost here. I know B1 = r*Sy/Sx and B0 = Ybar - B1 * Xbar

Comment: Hint: work backwards. The overall p-value also is the p-value for `x`, implying you can determine its t value, which gives you a way to convert the standard error into an estimate.

Comment: Hm. Since its simple linear regression F = T^2 correct? So i can find t that way. Not really making the connection on how to go from the t value to point estimate. I know SE(B1) = sd/sqrt(SSX).

Comment: (1) From $F=t^2$ you may conclude $t=\pm \sqrt{F}$: that ambiguity reveals the importance of the clue "I recall that it is positive."  (2) How is $t$ computed in terms of the estimate and its standard error?

Comment: so would i set the t i found equal to x/std error?

Comment: Rather than guess, why not examine other regression output to confirm your suppositions?